# When do the weekly brawls reset?

Tags: overwatch

Overwatch has a weekly brawl, which is a rotating custom gamemode that rotates on a weekly basis. However, right now, the brawl is "Arcade", which I'm not a giant fan of. When do the brawls rotate? Every Tuesday since that's when the game released? Or is it on a different day of the week?

Comment: Blizzard does weekly maintenance on Tuesday morning, so likely that's when they will reset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They change on Tuesdays at 22:00 UTC according to [this](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20744945104#post-5) blue post.